# MySQL did not start after setting defaults-file

Tags: mysql, collation, character-set

I am trying to set character_set_server and server_collation to utf8 and utf8_polish_ci to have polish chars in database.

I am using MySQL 5.7.10 and as I know I cannot do this after installation.

I tried this:

```
mysqld --character-set-server=utf8 --collation-server=utf8_polish_ci
```

but it did not work.

Defaults language settings in this version of MySQL is latin1.

I tried also to add config file with this properties setting inside, but after

```
mysqld.exe --install MyDatabaseServiceName --defaults-file=myconfig.cnf
```

is no error, but service did not start.

When I am using services.msc I can see MyDatabaseServiceName Running but it's never Run.

I also tried to use MySql 8.0.10 version, but my application using Entity Framework and as MySql manual advice I install additional MySql.Data.Entity.EF6 which version is 6.9.8.

After it Visual Studio told me I need .NET connector in version 6.9.8 not 8.0.10 (like database version).

When I downgrade libs command line told me about sha2_hashing password error, because default root password hashing for this version is SHA2 but this is supported by .Net connector >8.0.

So I am stuck at this point and I don't know how to resolve this problem.

P.S - I tried to set character_set and collation and each table, column but after it my database still losing polish characters after saving data to database.

Comment: Try to start the deamon from command line and not as server, you may get some error outputs

Comment: "Deamon" ? what u mean?

Comment: Mysql daemon (server) can start as Service or as a normal process using a command line to start. Sometimes using the command line is useful to get some error outputs. Are you working in Windows or Linux?

Comment: I am working at Windows and I am using command line to install mysql. I am doing it 
mysqld.exe --install MyDatabaseServiceName --defaults-file=myconfig.cnf
and it give me no errors.

Comment: Find the error file.  Surely there was a message there.  Meanwhile, there is no need to restart the server with `--collation-server=...`; just set it in my.cnf.

Comment: I mean to start the server after installation using command line, for example: `C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.7\my.ini"`. (if it starts, to stop it type CTRL-C)

Comment: I found only one file with .err which has no error inside, only one warning about explicit timestamp. I tried also setting config file first and than do install but an MySql Manual says I should do it in h\the same command like I made above.
Any other ideas? Or  should I just take another database type like PostgreSQL ?